# How to return a value from a for statement in a method in c#

Tags: c#

I can't figure out why this code can't return `result` in the factorial method. Any help would be appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CalculatorProgram
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("What is the first number:\n> ");
            decimal x = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Write("What is the second integer:\n> ");
            decimal y = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Write("What is the operation that you would like to use? 
Enter + , - , * , / , or ! :\n> ");
            string operation = Console.ReadLine();

            if (operation == "!")
            {
                Console.Write("Which number would you like to use?\n> ");
                int num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("{0}! = {1}", num, Factorial(num));
            }
        }

        private static int Factorial(int a)
        {
            int result;
            for (int i = 1; i < a + 1; i++ )
            {
                result = a * i;
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you debug the code?

Comment: The compiler has given you an error telling you what you're doing wrong. Why are you ignoring it? Hint: what is the result, you think, when `a = 0`?

Comment: @JeroenMostert: Does it really? C# for president!

Comment: CS0165, use of unassigned local variable, and one of the reasons C# has beaten C++ in the local elections. :-P

Comment: Way too much code. Read about [mcve].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`result = a * i;` is incorrect.

It should be something like `result = result * i;`, with `result` initialised to 1: i.e. change `int result;` to `int result = 1;`.

Currently you're evaluating `a * a`.

Comment: `result` is still "undefined" though. I just can't figure out why.

Comment: @EzraBoyd: Did you initialise it to 1?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
private static int Factorial(int a)
{
    int result = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i < a + 1; i++)
    {
        result = result * i;
    }

    return result;
}
```